# downloading and installing error: package is not a debian format archive

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I'm a newbie to Linux and Ubuntu, and I'm trying to install a package called `libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2` I first use wget

```
wget http://packages.ubuntu.com/dapper/libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2
```

It gives me `saving to libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2.4` so it adds an extra `.4` at the end. Then I do

```
sudo dpkg -i libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2.4
```

and it gives me

```
dpkg-deb: error: `libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2.4' is not a debian format archive
dpkg: error processing libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2.4 (--install):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2.4
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no package by the name of libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2. You can check this by going to the URL that you have mentioned in the question: http://packages.ubuntu.com/dapper/libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2.

When you run wget for the above URL, you end up downloading the web page (check the wget command output which states that you are downloading text/html).

If you want to install the C++ compiler and the C++ STL, then just install g++. `sudo apt-get install g++`.

Answer (score 3):

In general you should install from the package management system (using the Software Centre or Synaptic or Muon or apt-get etc), instead of downloading deb files this way. Why do you want to install libstdc++2.10-glibc2.2? Are you actually using Ubuntu 6.06 Dapper Drake?